# How to multiply only the odd rows of a matrix while still keeping the even rows?

Tags: r

If there were a matrix, example:

```
m <- matrix(c(1:4), nrow = 4, ncol=4)
```

how would I go about multiplying only the odd rows by an arbitrary scalar while still keeping the even rows in the same place and the same value?

In this example, the matrix with only odd rows being multiplied by two would become:

```
1 1 1 1          2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2          2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3    ----> 6 6 6 6
4 4 4 4          4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass bool vector to matrix, and if it divisible with number of rows r will replicate it.

```
mat <- matrix(1:4,4,4)
mat[c(TRUE,FALSE),] <- mat[c(TRUE,FALSE),] * 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    6    6    6    6
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R code using `diag()` + `rep()`

```
diag(rep(c(2,1),nrow(mat)/2))%*% mat
```

such that

```
> diag(rep(c(2,1),nrow(mat)/2))%*% mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    6    6    6    6
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```